# How do I get latitude longtitude values in array and how do I set in mapbox using android?

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, mapbox

Don't know how do i get array of latitude , longtitude values in android and i want to set markers for that array values in map using mapbox ?

Please can you help me in this issue...

Answer (score 0):

Please do some research before posting questions.

MapBox has documentation on how to draw and configure markers [here](https://www.mapbox.com/help/android-markers/). You can look up how to loop through arrays and retrieve values in Java to get your longitude and latitude values.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to write a "class LocationService extends Service" where you will fetch longitude and latitude values on location change, then implement these values in MapBox (any way you prefer).